# Not able to read kafka topic from another Host

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

I have two hosts A and B. A has zookeeper and kafka(0.9.0.1) installed. B has spark installed on it.
Now when im trying to read the kafka topic from A through spark streaming and persist the data in to B.
Here is the issue, when i run the spark app, it thoroughly throws the below errors continously,

```
17/04/20 05:22:16 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Error starting receiver 0 - kafka.common.ConsumerRebalanceFailedException: OlapEventsJamba_appEvent_HOSTA-1492680125896-b52bf576 can't rebalance after 4 retries
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener.syncedRebalance(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:660)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$$reinitializeConsumer(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:967)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.consume(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:254)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:156)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:597)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:587)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1979)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1979)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/04/20 05:22:16 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 80, prd-mapr-node1.fishbowl.com): kafka.common.ConsumerRebalanceFailedException: OlapEventsJamba_appEvent_HOSTA-1492680125896-b52bf576 can't rebalance after 4 retries
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener.syncedRebalance(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:660)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$$reinitializeConsumer(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:967)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.consume(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:254)
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:156)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver.onStart(KafkaInputDStream.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:597)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:587)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1979)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1979)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Below are the steps I tried to resolve the issue**

set the following values in consumer.props and zookeeper.props

```
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=1000000
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=10000
rebalance.backoff.ms=10000
```

Both A and B are telnet'ing and pinging.

Then, I tried to print the schema of the topic message, but the output is only

```
root
```

Spark app was creating a _success file in the output directory though.

Here is a snap of the zookeeper logs:

```
 [2017-04-20 09:49:23,648] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15b8aa804290015 type:create cxid:0x79 zxid:0x1a1f txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a
 Error Path:/consumers/test-group/owners/topic_test/0 Error:KeeperErrorCode = InvalidACL for /consumers/test-group/owners/topic_test/0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
    [2017-04-20 09:49:25,978] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15b8aa804290015 type:create cxid:0xea zxid:0x1a20 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a 
Error Path:/consumers/test-group/owners/topic_test/0 Error:KeeperErrorCode = InvalidACL for /consumers/test-group/owners/topic_test/0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
    [2017-04-20 09:49:28,320] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15b8aa804290015 type:create cxid:0x15b zxid:0x1a21 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a
 Error Path:/consumers/test-group/owners/topic_test/0 Error:KeeperErrorCode = InvalidACL for /consumers/test-group/owners/topic_test/0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
    [2017-04-20 09:49:30,653] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15b8aa804290015 type:create cxid:0x1cc zxid:0x1a22 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a
 Error Path:/consumers/test-group/owners/topic_test/0 Error:KeeperErrorCode = InvalidACL for /consumers/test-group/owners/topic_test/0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
```

What can be the issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Whether B also have Zookeeper and Kafka installed? If yes, you should not see this issue as both the brokers configuration will be saved to zookeeper. 

But if Broker is not installed on B and if you pass the data from A to B, either you need to define some pipeline or you can use Spark's pipe API.

Comment: B don't have kafka and zookeeper installed on it. Is this mandatory as well?

Comment: @ishan can you point me towards a valid link to fulfil my requirements

Comment: fixed this issue by changing the zookeeper conf, and i have used talend application to consume the messages from the topic